# Hudson: Build nightly only when codebase or snapshot dependency is changed

Tags: continuous-integration, hudson, nightly-build

I have a separate job to build a project during the night. But I only want to build it if the code of the project is changed **or** snapshot dependency of the project is built.

Building a project nightly when codebase was changed can be achieved using SCM polling schedule. But how I can combine it together with "Build whenever SNAPSHOT dependency is built"?

Answer (score 1):

I assume that those snapshots also exist as jobs in your Hudson.
(if this is false, please say so in the comment)

- For each project, do a nightly SCM polling (like you have done).
- In dependent jobs, go to **Build Triggers** and tick **Build after other projects are built** (it's directly under "Build whenever a SNAPSHOT dependency is built") and enter those snapshots projects you mentioned. Do **not** tick the "Build whenever a SNAPSHOT dependency is built".
- Go to **Advanced Project Options** and tick the **Block build when upstream project is building**.
- You may also want to space out the polling time, so if the first one is "0 0 * * *", the next one can be set to "0 1 * * *" (i.e., 1 hour after the next).

Comment: I do not quite understand what are you suggesting. I want to build the project **only** during the night. I do no want to build the project immediately when a snapshot dependency is changed.

Comment: Edited my answer, I hope it's clearer now. I had assumed that the configuration started from the default.

Comment: If I have project A dependent on project B, your solution assumes that I have two nightly build jobs -- one for project A and another for B? What I want to have is two jobs -- one nightly build job for project A and another "ordinary" (on scm change) one for B.

Comment: Then just create a new Hudson job for the same project. So now you have A, B, B'.